# Django admin show only current user for User field as ForeignKey while creating and object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-4.0

I'm working on a Django ( 4.0 +) project, where I have a model named `Post` in which we have a ForignKey field as `Author`, a user with `is_staff` and in `Authors` group can create an object of `Post` from admin.

Now the problem is when user click on `Add Post` as the `Author` field it should only display the current user not the others.

Here's what i have tried:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='category')
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**From `admin.py`:**

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status','created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `a user with is_staff` vs `if request.user.is_superuser`

Comment: a user with `is_staff` in this case

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what was the expected and invalid behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to simply exclude the field from the form, and assign the user when you save the model with the [**`.save_model(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model):

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status', 'created_on')
    list_filter = ('status',)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    exclude = ('author',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(author=request.user)
        return qs

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Now it gives another error as:
`IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

Comment: @AbdulRehman: well you should look wat foreign key that is. Likely because you inject some value in a `ForeignKey` that does not match with a valid database record.

Answer (score 0):

Try [formfield_for_foreignkey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

It overrides the default formfield for a foreign keys field. In your case, to return only current user for `author` foreign key field:

```python
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'author':
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```